# GroupBy then Take in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, entities, take

Let's say I have the following items:

```
ID      Category        Name

1       Fruit           Banana
2       Car             Mescedes
3       Fruit           Blackberry
4       Fruit           Mango
5       Car             Lexus
6       Fruit           Melon
7       Car             BMW
8       Car             Toyota
```

I want to group them into `Category` and take only the first 3 items of each `Category`. Is it possible?

I expected the output:

```
ID        Category        Name

1        Fruit           Banana
3        Fruit           Blackberry
4        Fruit           Mango
2        Car             Mescedes
5        Car             Lexus
7        Car             BMW
```

Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain what you expect the output of this to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From head and not tested:

```
from c in categoryList
group by c.Category into g
let fewItems = g.Take(3).ToList()
return new { Category = g.Key, Items = fewItems }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you list collection is named as categoryList..

The linq queries to achive what you want is:

```
categoryList.GroupBy(c=>c.Category).Take(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for ur fast reply. I missed the most important part. The first 3 items of `each category`, not all.